# Autocomplete TextBox that follows MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, autocomplete, combobox

I have a textbox and I want to make it an autocomplete text box. 
The data I am going to show when I type the textbox is from my datagrid. My datagrid has 4 columns and I can pick any column from the datagrid.

Here is my textbox

```
         <TextBox Margin="0,93,39,18" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="325">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SearchHint}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```

DataGrid

```
    <DataGrid Name="Datagrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" Margin="4,0,380,413" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
    IsReadOnly="True"  RowBackground="WhiteSmoke" >
```

I googled and most of the samples I got doesn't follow WPF/MVVM pattern. What I am about to do is bind the textblock data to the grid items.Can someone help me by giving me points on where to start.

Comment: check this maybe help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31947/WPF-AutoComplete-Folder-TextBox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to approach this question, but arguably the most prominent is the editable combobox strategy (they ask a lot of questions about this in Microsoft's WPF exam which totally IGNORE the MVVM pattern, but that's an issue for another day).  I'll give an example to get you started.  The first step is to code up a combobox and datagrid...

```
  <StackPanel>
            <ComboBox
             IsEditable="True"
             IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
             SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
            >
                <ComboBox.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding  Key="Enter" Command="{Binding NotImplementedCommand}"/>
                </ComboBox.InputBindings>
            </ComboBox>
                <DataGrid
                ItemsSource="{Binding DriveList}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                />
        </StackPanel>
```

And then create a ViewModel...

```
public class ViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyItems { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DriveInfo> DriveList { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        DriveList = new ObservableCollection<DriveInfo>();
        foreach (DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            DriveList.Add(di);
        }
        DriveListCollectionChanged(null, null);
        DriveList.CollectionChanged += DriveListCollectionChanged;

    }
    void DriveListCollectionChanged(object sender, 
                        System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyItems.Clear();
        List<string> temp = new List<string>();
        foreach (DriveInfo di in DriveList)
        {// add 4 columns from the DataGrid to the auto complete source
            temp.Add(di.Name);
            temp.Add(di.DriveType.ToString());
            if (di.IsReady)
            {
                temp.Add(di.DriveFormat);
                temp.Add(di.TotalSize.ToString());
                temp.Add(di.AvailableFreeSpace.ToString());
            }
        }
        foreach (string s in temp.Distinct())
        {
            MyItems.Add(s);
        }
    }
    private string _mySelectedItem;
    public string MySelectedItem
    {
        get { return _mySelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _mySelectedItem)
            {
                _mySelectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string s)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(s));
        }
    }
}
```

This example interrupts the event where the DataGrid's source is changed and populates the combo box with MULTIPLE columns.  If you were just doing a single column, the solution here would vary.  There is also some binding esoterica where you can automatically bind the combobox to the data, but its didactic value is questionable given what you have asked and your intent to add multiple columns of heterogeneous strings  to a combobox.

You'll need to better optimize the event handler before deploying your app because the one shown above is only for demonstration purposes.

To wire this up, put this (or its alternate) in your Xaml...

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <wpfApplication3:ViewModel  x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
        <!-- your xaml -->
    </Grid>
```

The ViewModel class above is an MVVM compliant solution, and you would bind an instance of this class to the DataContext of the presenting view.

Comment: thanks for the guid. I didnt get this part:                       <ComboBox.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding  Key="Enter" Command="{Binding NotImplementedCommand}"/>
                    </ComboBox.InputBindings>

Comment: That part anticipates the need to handle the situation where the user hits the enter key after typing something in the combobox.  You can safely ignore it until the need arises.

Comment: I am trying to bind to the VM like this  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="198,93,448,10"  DataContext="{Binding Source={local:SearchViewModel}}" > but i am getting this error: viewModels:SearchViewModel' is used like a markup extension but does not derive from MarkupExtension.

Comment: Hang on.  That's a different binding from your original xaml and not using the sample I gave where the VM included all the bindings.  Did my solution not help you?

Comment: everything is the same except I gave it a different name from ViewModel => SearchViewModel and on the XAML I added DataContext="{Binding Source={local:SearchViewModel}}" to point to the VM

Comment: That error means you are trying to bind with an illegal markup extension.  In my answer, you bind the VM to the DataContext of the *Window*, not the grid itself.  Otherwise the VM will not be able to operate on the other controls!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32117/discussion-between-ayda-sayed-and-garry-vass)